# Adding multiple entries to table

Tags: database

I've got a website where users can make recipes.

So I've got a table called `ingredients` with ingredients

So the user selects the ingredients he/she wants with the amount required, and then I will store this in a new table called `recipes`

But I wonder what's the best practice for storing this

I was thinking like this

**RECIPES**

```
Id | UserId | IngredientId  
-------------------------- 
0  | 23     | 3,6,7,9,2,1    
1  | 56     | 8,2,6,7,1  
2  | 80     | 1,7,3,2,7  
3  | 11     | 6,7,4,3,21,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider having join tables. It would work something like this:

```
User
Id | Name
0 | Bob Smith
1 | Susie Jones

Recipe
Id | Name
0 | Ramen
1 | Pizza

Ingredient
Id | Name
0 | Flour
1 | Water
2 | Yeast

User_Recipe
User_Id | Recipe_Id
0 | 1
1 | 0

Recipe_Ingredient
Recipe_Id | Ingredient_Id | Quantity
1 | 0 | 1 C.
1 | 1 | 1/2 C.
1 | 2 | 1 T.
```

Comment: I am 38 seconds late :(. +1 for the schema - I merged `recipes` and `user_recipes` tables... it might not be 100% normalized

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complex your application is. Your table is not [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as you have written it. On the other hand, my way might be an overkill for a small application, but I would propose the following schema:

1. Table `users`

   This table contains your user information and each row has a unique user `id` (as I understand you already have this)
2. Table `ingredients`

   Here you store your ingredients that also have a unique `id`. Also, this does not contain any recipe information like quantity but instead has only ingredient attributes like: `name`, `description`, `form`, `price_per_kilo`, etc.
3. Table `recipes`

   This table is a many-to-many relationship between `user`s and `recipes`. Again, it contains only recipe attributes like: `user_id`, `name`, `date_created`, `rating`, `difficulty`, `instructions`, etc
4. Table `recipe_ingredients`

   Finally, this table lists all the ingredients a recipe requires, including the amount. Columns would be `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id`, `amount`, `unit`, `comment`, etc

Hope it helps